# Is there a way to write a comboBox selection to a text file that is read by a tableLayoutPanel then displayed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two Forms. One form is for the tableLayoutPanel (Form2) and another for my pop up with the comboBoxes (CT).
My goal is to make it so that when in input my selection into the comboBoxes it saves the files numerically and separately. I also want it to have a system to check if the file exists so that when I reload the app it carries on the count. In addition, I would like to add to the code so that when a text file is made it shows up on my tableLayoutPanel (on Form2).

So far with this issue I have made it so that it counts numerically but when I close the app it re-writes the .txt files.

Thank you.

CT code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            Count++;
        }
        string selectedsite = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        string selectedsize = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        string selectedproduct = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem);
        string selectedproxies = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox4.SelectedItem);
        string selectedprofiles = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox5.SelectedItem);
        string[] FileInfo = { selectedsite, " ", selectedsize, " ", selectedproduct, " ", selectedproxies, " ", selectedprofiles };
        var newFileName = string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count);
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(string.Format(@"D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks\{0}.txt", Count)))
        {
            Count++;
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, FileInfo);

    }
```

Comment: What technology stack are you using? Windows Forms? .net core or .net full framework? Which version?

Comment: windows forms c# :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static class to keep track of where the file count has got to.

```
namespace StackOverflow69153275FileCounter
{
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;

    public static class FileCounter
    {
        private static string dataFolder;
        private static int count;

        public static void Initialise()
        {
            dataFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DataFolder");
            if (!Directory.Exists(dataFolder))
            {
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException($"Folder '{dataFolder}' doesn't exist!");
            }
        }

        public static string NextFile
        {
            get
            {
                var nextFile = GetFullPath(count);
                while (File.Exists(nextFile))
                {
                    count++;
                    nextFile = GetFullPath(count);
                }

                return nextFile;
            }
        }

        private static string GetFullPath(int count)
        {
            return Path.Combine(dataFolder, $"{count}.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

This expects your app.config file to contain the path to where the files are created, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DataFolder" value="D:\Bot\Bot\Tasks"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You need to initialise the `FileCounter` class in the constructor of your application's main form (or you could do it in the Program.cs class, as long as it's done on application startup).

```
public Form2()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    FileCounter.Initialise();
    label1.Text = FileCounter.NextFile;
}
```

And then in you button click event handler, you can just use the NextFile property to get the next available filename.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var fileInfo = new string[] { /* populate the file content here */ };
    File.WriteAllLines(FileCounter.NextFile, fileInfo);
    label1.Text = FileCounter.NextFile;
}
```